# Hide first x characters

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to hide the first x character of a h4 element via css?

For example:

```
<h4>Data: This is some random data.</h4>
```

"Data: " shall not be shown.

I tried overflow and moving the div which contains h4, this works, but it isn't a good solution for me.

Maybe there's an command I don't know about which helps. I know JavaScript and strreplace would work as well, but I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Wrap the `Data:` with an element and hide it!

Comment: I don't think it's possible without something like a span wrapped around 'data'.

Comment: The only way to do it dynamically with CSS is to set a `max-width` and use `text-overflow`.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible, because every h4 is created dynamically through an XML file. I have to work with the h4 as it is :/

Comment: How are you loading the XML into the markup? That's where I'd intercept the text and modify it.

Comment: Via jquery, unfortunately I don't know very much about jquery. That's why I was looking for quick solution via CSS.

Comment: That's fine, I definitely think you should modify the text there before adding it to the HTML. You can't do it with CSS only, but this is easy enough. You can show us the part which builds the content from the XML in another question, and you'll get help in no time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like others have said, it's not possible to exactly what you want. But just for fun, if it's always "Data: " that you're trying to hide, you could do this:

```css
h4 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}

h4:before {
    content: "Data: ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h4>Data: This is some random data</h4>
```

But I agree with others, intercepting in the PHP is probably the best approach.

Comment: Nice idea, too bad it can't work when there's a background behind it. +1

Comment: This is BRILLIANT. In my case, any jquery solution would show for 1 seconds the text that i wanted to hide, and after hide it, while with this solution the text shows properly from the beginning. And this can be used further for other attribute if i wish, as opposed to a jquery solution that would hide let's say first 6 characters. You just saved my day!

Answer (score 12):

Try using text-indent with negative value and overflow hidden:

```
h4{
overflow-x: hidden;
text-indent: -10px;
}
```

And the best result would be if you have a monospace font and you look in a browser that supports `ch` units so that `text-indent: -4ch` would acctualy mean that you hide 4 characters.

Comment: Probably worth removing the extra 5px margin-bottom created by the hidden overflow-x (at least on Chrome)

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, CSS can't calculate the width of strings and has no access to textual content... If you were using monospace fonts, you'd be able to calculate the width manually, based on the font size, but it would still be a bad solution.

Negative margins, indents, etc. are unreliable as we have no idea about how the fonts are rendered, meaning it could all break and look ugly in different browsers, under different zoom levels, etc...

Bottom line: **CSS alone can't do it**

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so there isn't a pure CSS solution. But I found a pretty simple way to select the first word via jQuery and wrap it in a `<span>`.

```
jQuery(".first-word").each(function(){
    var me = $(this), fw = me.text().split(' ');
    me.html( '<span>' + fw.shift() + '</span> ' + fw.join(' ') );
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7w9ev0y6/)

Comment: Is it possible to run this before any element is loaded on the page? Running with $(document).ready(function() doesn't work.